# Error en el archivo Link.js de proyecto de React

Tags: reactjs

Estaba trabajando normalmente en un proyecto de react y de un momento a otro, al guardar un cambio resulta este error y no se a que se debe

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea de como podria solucionar esto?

Comment: La app fue hecha con [`create-react-app`](https://create-react-app.dev/) o fue manualmente configurada?

Comment: @JuanMarco Fue hecha con create-react-app, de un momento a otro empezo a salir ese error, volvi a un commit hecho el dia anterior, donde no presentaba este error y aun asi salia, cree una nueva app, pase solo archivos del SRC a la nueva app y aun asi sigue saliendo el mismo error.

Comment: Recordas si agregaste algun paquete (con yarn or npm) antes de que saliera ese error?

Comment: No, no agregue ninguno, venía trabajando normalmente

Comment: al parecer te falta una librería para corregir tiene que instalarla
para eso pon npm install

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas el plugin `@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx`.

Ejecuta `npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx` para instalarlo como dependencia de desarrollo, debería ser suficiente.